# Unable to implement React-table sever data loading

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, react-table

I am testing the React-table server side data to render a huge amount of data fetched from an web api without crashing the browser. With the base react-table settings the browser is unable to handle such amount of records (500000) and crash (it gets stuck in the pending state of the request).

So I find the server side data that maybe can help me. 
I followed the instructions from the documentation but typescript is complaining about the data that I am trying to use when I update the state.

This is what I have until now:

The method that fetch the data from web api:

```js
private fetchSales() {
  fetch(`http://localhost:50335/api/RK`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data =>
      this.setState({
        sales: data // here I get 500000 items 
      })
    )
}
```

This fetchSales gets called in the componentDidMount().

Then I have the ReactTable component inside the render():

```js
render() {
  const {
    sales,
    pages
  } = this.state;
  return ( 
    <div className = "App" >
    <ReactTable 
      data = {sales}
      manual 
      pages = {pages}
      defaultPageSize = {10}
      onFetchData = {this._fetchData}
      columns = {
      [{
          Header: "Region",
          accessor: "Region"
        },
        {
          Header: "Country",
          accessor: "Country"
        }]
      }
    />
    </div>
  );
}
```

In the ReactTable there is call to a function called _fetchData and that function looks like this:

```js
private _fetchData(state: any) {
  requestData(
    state.sales,
    state.pageSize,
    state.page
  ).
  then(res => {
    this.setState({
      sales: res.rows, // here typescript complain: "res is of type 'unknown'"
      pages: res.pages // here typescript complain: "res is of type 'unknown'"
    });
  })
}
```

Inside the setState the res object is type 'unknown' and typescript doesn't like it.

requestData is a function that lives outside the class and get the sales, pageSize and page states:

```js
const requestData = (sales: any, page: number, pageSize: number) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const res = {
      rows: sales.slice(pageSize * page, pageSize * page * pageSize),
      pages: Math.ceil(sales.length / pageSize)
    }

    resolve(res);
  })
}
```

The function is almost identical the in the documentation I only removed the filtering and sorting because I don't need them. I only need the res object that return the function.

And I almost forget it, inside the constructor I am attaching the this to the _fetchData method: this._fetchData = this._fetchData.bind(this);

Why is typescript complaining about the res object that I am trying to use to set the state?

Best regards!
Americo

Answer (score 0):

EDIT

I noticed a few mistakes.

```
private _fetchData(state: any) {
  requestData(
    state.sales, // that should be state.data (state is the state of ReactTable)
    state.pageSize,
    state.page
...
```

Next, I've noticed that you do pagination after fetching the data. But using `manual` with `onFetchData` is for handling pagination on the **server**. For example, with `page` and `pageSize` you could pass these parameters to your API. That's the whole point of pagination!

An example from the documentation:

```
onFetchData={(state, instance) => { //onFetchData is called on load and also when you click on 'next', when you change page, etc.
    // show the loading overlay
    this.setState({loading: true})
    // fetch your data
    Axios.post('mysite.com/data', {
      //These are all properties provided by ReactTable
      page: state.page,
      pageSize: state.pageSize,
      sorted: state.sorted,
      filtered: state.filtered
    })
```

Since you're fetching all of them at once (why though? can't your API on the server handle pagination? this way, you won't have to wait ages before the results are returned), then I suggest you let ReactTable do the work.

That is, you just do:

```
<ReactTable
  columns={columns}
  data={data}
/>
```

ReactTable will take care of pagination. And now, you may use your query to the API in `ComponentDidMount`.

---

Could you please instead try to put all the logic in the onFetchData. I could be wrong but it seems to me you misunderstood the instructions in the documentation. `OnFetchData` is called at `ComponentDidMount`, it's not telling you that you have to put your function there.

```
private _fetchData(state, instance) {

  const { page, pageSize } = state

  fetch(`http://localhost:50335/api/RK`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data =>
         let sales = data
         this.setState({
           sales: sales.slice(pageSize * page, pageSize * page * pageSize),
           pages: Math.ceil(sales.length / pageSize)
         });
    )
}
```

As for Typescript, from what I gather, Typescript doesn't have enough information to infer the type of what your Promise returns.

So you have to explicitly annotate Promises generic type parameter:

```
return new Promise<{ sales: object; pages: number; }>((resolve, reject) => { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!
I will test it

Comment: I did a test and its work almost perfect with the changes that you recommended. The only thing that doesn't work is that when the application starts the list is empty and that is why I called the _fetchData function on the componentDidMount. Right now i need to trigger an event in the react table in order to call the _fetchData and populate the list. Do you know a way to populate the table when the application loads?